# Next JS deployment on vercel constantly failing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

My Next JS deployed site's vercel build is constantly failing.Here's the screenshot of the error.
[image: Deployment Error]

I don't exactly know what's happening. Everything works fine locally.

Comment: What error? there doesn't seems to be any error. Did you wait for it to complete? it's suppose to upload the files to the cdn after that. It will take a while.

Comment: any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Building from more than 30 mins

Answer (score 0):

After those steps in the screenshot.. it will continue and you are suppose to see similar to the following

[image]

Comment: well that's the problem it's not showing these things

Comment: I guess that will be a question for vercel's github support page or vercel's support then..

Comment: Ok @Someone Special